# Matlab Remove empty cell array content

Tags: matlab, cells

I have 5*14 matrix (m*n)

```
M={'a','b',.....' ',' ' ;
   'aa','bb',...' ',' ' ;
    ... }
```

whats the best option to remove empty cells to be (5*n) after removing empty cells:

```
M={'a','b','c';
   'aa','bb' ;
   'e';
   'aa','xx';
   ...}
```

When i do this:

```
emptyCells = cellfun('isempty', M);
cols = size(M,2);
M(emptyCells) = [];
M = reshape(M, [], cols);
```

I get error :`Error using reshape
Product of known dimensions, 14, not divisible into total number of elements, 52.`

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is impossible. In a Matrix every row has the same number of elements. Could you rethink your expected output? Maybe a nested array? `M={{'a','b','c'};{ 'aa','bb'} ; {'e'}; {'aa','xx'}}`?

Comment: okay output may be nested array,but could u tell me  the  idea to achieve this output  ?

Comment: Just wondering, does each row have to have the same number of columns after removing empty cells? If so, do we just pad the end of shorter rows with ' '?

Comment: no ,each row doesn't have the same number of columns. My question was to remove ' ' not to pad the with ' ' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution creating a nested cell:

```
M={'a','b','c';'d','e','';'','','';'','f',''};
%Convert cell to nested cell
M=mat2cell(M,ones(size(M,1),1));
%now apply your code to every subcell
for ix=1:numel(M)
    emptyCells = cellfun('isempty', M{ix});
    M{ix}(emptyCells)=[];
end
```